# Case-insensitive compare of Turkish file names in .NET

Tags: .net, string, internationalization, case-insensitive, turkish

How should file names be compared in .NET?

I've read that `InvariantCulture` is preferred, but here's my problem...

A case-insensitive compare of a Turkish file name with the classic "I" vs. "i" issue, where, "İSMİNİZ.GIF" to be equivalent to "isminiz.gif". The "i" in "isminiz" is the same as "İ" in "İSMİNİZ", but the "i" in "gif" compares with "I" in "GIF".

None of the String.Equals methods work. The only combination I could find is

```
String.Compare("İSMİNİZ.GIF", "isminiz.gif", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | 
    System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace)
```

Is this correct or is there something better?